# Hi i am struggling with a formula

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, formula

I have an excel spreadsheet with the following formula in column "L":

`=IF($A4="","",IF($J4>=$K4,"",IF($J4="","",if($M4<>"Released","",$J4+90)))`

I am trying to populate Column "L" with a date 90 days from column "J" but only if either Column M=Released or if Column K is greater than J on any other occasion Column "L" must remain blank

I can get the formula to work if I remove the IF($J4>=$K4,"", element and just have

`=IF($A4=""," ",IF($M4<>"Released","",IF($J4="","",$J4+90)))`

or just with this element

`=IF($A4="","",IF($J4>=$K4,"",IF($J4="","",$J4+90)))`

but when I try to add **`IF($J4>=$K4,""** and **IF($M4<>"Released",""`** together I can't get it to work

Appreciate any advice

Comment: If you nest IF statements like that your result will be AND not OR, i.e. your current formula will populate L if  M = Released AND K > J.    Is that the problem you are having?

Comment: Because Cell M is not equal to Released (in this case = Terminated) the 90 day follow up is not being populated despite Cell K being greater then cell J.  Cell "L4" remains blank ( E.g. Cell A is populated, Cell J = 31/03/2020 Cell K = 12/4/2020 and cell M = "terminated" ) this should mean cell L should = 29/6/2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement and formula are in disagreement.

`=IF($A4="","",IF(OR($J4>=$K4,$M4<>"Released"),$J4+90,""))`

**Edit:**

Based on OP's input

`=IF($A4="","",IF($M4="Released",$J4+90,IF(AND($M4="Terminated",$K4>$J4),$J4+90,"")))`

Comment: this works for row 4 where the date in cell K is greater than J, thank you but, when J is equal to K or less, then cell L still gets populated even if I change >= to just >  I don't want it to populate if column M = Terminated and the date in K is equal to or less than J

Comment: @RachelTaylor, you will have to provide a clear statement. Up to first part ($A4), formula seems to be clear. Now clarify the balance part. Do we need to check (J Vs K) before we go and check M? Or is it either condition?

Comment: Checking M should be first if = "Released" then the follow up date should be populated.  Checking J Vs K is only if M is = "Terminated"  If = "Terminated" and if K is > J then M should be populated.

Comment: @RachelTaylor Please check edited answer which is based on your description.

Answer (score 0):

I test ok with your formula,

```
=IF($A4="","",IF($J4>=$K4,"",IF($J4="","",if($M4<>"Released","",$J4+90))))
```

your formula do less a ")" at the last,
However, I believe that you should be prompted by the Excel to correct the formula.

The Excel should correct the mistake for you automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not populate Cell "L4" with a 90 day follow up date despite K4 being greater than J4 and M4 note equal to "Released" ( E.g. Cell A is populated, Cell J = 31/03/2020 Cell K = 12/4/2020 and cell M = "terminated" )

Comment: with your example, ( E.g. Cell A is populated, Cell J = 31/03/2020 Cell K = 12/4/2020 and cell M = "terminated" ) 

```
if($M4<>"Released","",$J4+90)
```

That is what the condition you set in the Formula, When M4 not equal to "Released" then get "".

Comment: I don't want it to populate if cell M = Terminated and the date in K is equal to or less than J any other I.e. if the date is greater or cell M = Released then cell L should be populated with a 90 day follow up date